# Как разделить строку на отдельные слова и вставить в вектор на c++

Tags: python, c++

Строка: "Фамилия Имя Отчество"

массив(Вектор): [Фамилия;Имя;Отчество]

В python можно было использовать функция map и метод split для разделение строки на слова.
Может есть встроенные функции в плюсах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно так:

```
std::vector<std::string> res;

std::istringstream ss(text);
  
std::string word;
  
while (ss >> word) 
{
    res.push_back(word);
}
```

Comment: Более модный способ: `std::istringstream ss(text);` `std::vector<std::string> res(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ss), {});`.

Comment: я начинающий программист обучающийся в универе. Мне первый вариант более понятен, чем второй, но все же хотелось уточнить, что означат ss>>word и что делает stringstream. В интернете тяжело найти русскоязычный форум, где можно почитать об этом. Не могли бы кратко описать свой код?

Comment: `istringstream` - это строковый поток (почитайте - https://ravesli.com/urok-210-potokovye-klassy-i-stroki/) - по сути ваша строка превращается в набор слов (разделитель - пробел) и по оператору `>>` вам последовательно выдают слова, выделенные из строки. Это похоже как вы из файла читаете построчно, а здесь как будто в каждой строке 1 слово